# Replace cell value only if 2 columns have matching data

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 worksheets.  I want to loop through all the rows and compare column A in worksheet 1 with column A in worksheet 2.

If there is a match, I want to take the date from worksheet 2 column H in each row where column A in the 2 worksheets is a match and insert it in the corresponding row in worksheet 1 in column I.

If there is no match between the values in column A, then I want to leave the value in worksheet 1 column I unchanged.

Can you help me with an answer to this?

Comment: Insert a new column I in worksheet 1 (this will move the column I values to column J).  Assuming your data has headers, then in the new cell I2 (of the newly inserted blank column), use a VLOOKUP formula and copy down: `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,'worksheet 2'!A:H,8,FALSE),J2)` and then hide column J.  Or you can copy column I -> paste special -> values and then delete column J if preferred.

Answer (score 0):

This works on a workbook I created with two Sheets.

You need to add this to the cell where you want the info to go to, in your case the Date, in column I of worksheet1.

You will need to replace the name of the sheets and cells in the formula so that it works on your workbook.

In my example the sheets are named Sheet1 and Sheet2.
The cells I am comparing are I2 in Sheet1 and I2 in Sheet2
and the value I am copying from Sheet2 is A2 if there is a match
if there is no match I am passing an empty string "".

=IF(Sheet1!I2=Sheet2!I2,Sheet2!A2,"")

IF(Sheet1 cell I2 is equals to Sheet2 cell I2, copy the value of Sheet2 cell A2, if it is not equals copy nothing.

If you see a mistake please feel free to correct it as I am learning myself.

I hope this is of some help, good luck